# Is there a way of calling a script tag and style tag from within a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I am trying to implement something like this:

```
function ()
{
     <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
}
```

Basically I want to load a `.js` file from a `function`. Any advice would be very helpful.

Comment: check the link http://www.sitepoint.com/dynamically-load-jquery-library-javascript/

Comment: In addition to the question this is marked a duplicate of, here's a very capable function for loading scripts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989020/javascript-multiple-dynamic-insertion/6989187#6989187

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadjs(src){
  var js=document.createElement('script')
  js.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
  js.setAttribute("src", src)
}



//loadjscssfile("https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js")
```